# Overflow X Hidden not working on Mobile devices for my Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

The overflow x in my react Navbar not working as expected. The navbar is meant to slide in only when the Hamburger is clicked and not to show when not clicked. Everything works well except the fact that the overflow X that was supposed to hide keeps scrolling. Have tried a few things but yet not working.

Here is the link to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-villani-emxpi?file=/src/styles.css)

My Navbar and my CSS code are here below. Kindly help me look into this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import { MdMenu } from "react-icons/md";
// import { MdClose } from "react-icons/md";

export default function Navbar() {
    const[navLinkOpen, navLinkToggle] = useState(false)
    const handleNavLinksToggle = () =>{
        navLinkToggle(!navLinkOpen)
    }
    const renderClasses = () =>{
        let classes = "navlinks";
        if(navLinkOpen){
            classes += " active"
        }
        return classes;
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
     <nav>
     <div className="logo">
          <a href="/">Edie</a>
      </div>
      <ul className={renderClasses()}>
          <li className="link"> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
          <li className="link"> <a href="/">Services</a> </li>
          <li className="link"> <a href="/">Our Works</a> </li>
          <li className="link"> <a href="/">Clients</a> </li>
          <li className="link"> <a href="/">Contacts</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#000000", size: "30px", className: "icon" }}>
      <div onClick={handleNavLinksToggle} className="hamburger-toggle">
          <MdMenu/>
      </div>
      </IconContext.Provider>
     </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo&family=Poppins&display=swap');
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.navlinks{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo{
    width: 70px;
    height: 53px;
}

.logo > a{
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 53px;
color: #333333;
}

.navlinks > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 36px;
color: #333333;
}

.hamburger-toggle{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    body{
       overflow-x:  hidden;
    }

    .hamburger-toggle{
        display: block;
    }

.navlinks{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 92vh;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10vh;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use the position relative and additional width for html and body in global css.

It appears that browsers that parse the  tag simply ignore overflow attributes on the html and body tags.

on Global CSS

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```